# pandas groupby & aggregate into original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Original dataframe is:

```
                       open  high  low  close
2018-01-01 09:30:00    22.2  24.4  21.1  23.3
2018-01-01 09:35:00
.
.
.
2018-03-09 15:00:00
```

and I want to calculate Open/high/low/close on daily/weekly/monthly basis and aggregate the results and relevant index (week, month) into the original dataframe with multi-index as below:

```
open_day  open_week  open_month              open  high  low   close
2018-Jan  1st-week   2018-01-01   09:30:00   22.2  24.4  21.1  23.3
                                  09:35:00
.
.
.
```

Comment: You are more likely to get a helpful answer if you post an example of the code you have tried along with a description of why it isn't producing your expected result.

Comment: agree, but honestly, I am still drafting the codes to achieve my desired behavior, and I was not able to come up with any codes. That is why I can only describe my expected behavior here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need

```
df.assign(open_month=df.index.strftime('%Y%B'),
  open_week=df.index.strftime('%W'),
  open_date=df.index.date,
  open_time=df.index.time).\
   set_index(['open_month','open_week','open_date','open_time'])
Out[235]: 
                                            open  high   low  close
open_month  open_week open_date  open_time                         
2018January 01        2018-01-01 09:30:00   22.2  24.4  21.1   23.3
                                 09:35:00   22.2  24.4  21.1   23.3
2018March   09        2018-03-01 09:35:00   22.2  24.4  21.1   23.3
```

Comment: @TianYan you need resample you can search resemble ohlc

Comment: thanks for the hints to further calculate open/high/low/close for each day/week/month and append them to original dataframe. I will research on resemble , resample, ohlc etc.. cheers.